# Limit in Spark SQL expression complexity on AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql

My ultimate goal is to add a calculated field to a large table in Spark SQL, something along these lines:

```
sqlContext.sql(" create table spktest2 as select cll.*, [big expression] as tst from spktest cll")
```

The issue is that when [big expression] has several hundred combinations of case/when expressions, then I get an error:

```
ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "processNext()V" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator" grows beyond 64 KB
```

The error log is over 16Mb large so unfortunately I cannot paste it all here. There's a whole dump of code in that log.

I have made a reproducible code snippet, and running in pyspark shell on AWS EMR it generates the error, however it is also too large for me to be able to post it entirely. So I made the expression shorter and in order to be sure to get the error you need to just add terms in the sum by copying some of the ones here already.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import sys

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.range(0, 500)
df.registerTempTable('df')
val = sqlContext.sql(" drop table if exists spktest")
val = sqlContext.sql(" create table spktest as SELECT id, id + 1 as x, id + 3 as y from df")
sqlContext.sql('select * from spktest').show()

val = sqlContext.sql(" drop table if exists spktest2")
val = sqlContext.sql(" create table spktest2 as select cll.*, ((case  when x = 1 then y - 2 when x = 1 then y + 2 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 2 then y - 3 when x = 4 then y + 3 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 3 then y - 4 when x = 9 then y + 4 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 4 then y - 5 when x = 16 then y + 5 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 5 then y - 6 when x = 25 then y + 6 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 6 then y - 7 when x = 36 then y + 7 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 7 then y - 8 when x = 49 then y + 8 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 8 then y - 9 when x = 64 then y + 9 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 9 then y - 10 when x = 81 then y + 10 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 10 then y - 11 when x = 100 then y + 11 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 11 then y - 12 when x = 121 then y + 12 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 12 then y - 13 when x = 144 then y + 13 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 13 then y - 14 when x = 169 then y + 14 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 14 then y - 15 when x = 196 then y + 15 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 15 then y - 16 when x = 225 then y + 16 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 16 then y - 17 when x = 256 then y + 17 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 17 then y - 18 when x = 289 then y + 18 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 18 then y - 19 when x = 324 then y + 19 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 19 then y - 20 when x = 361 then y + 20 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 20 then y - 21 when x = 400 then y + 21 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 21 then y - 22 when x = 441 then y + 22 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 22 then y - 23 when x = 484 then y + 23 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 23 then y - 24 when x = 529 then y + 24 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 24 then y - 25 when x = 576 then y + 25 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 25 then y - 26 when x = 625 then y + 26 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 26 then y - 27 when x = 676 then y + 27 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 27 then y - 28 when x = 729 then y + 28 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 28 then y - 29 when x = 784 then y + 29 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 29 then y - 30 when x = 841 then y + 30 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 30 then y - 31 when x = 900 then y + 31 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 31 then y - 32 when x = 961 then y + 32 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 32 then y - 33 when x = 1024 then y + 33 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 33 then y - 34 when x = 1089 then y + 34 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 34 then y - 35 when x = 1156 then y + 35 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 35 then y - 36 when x = 1225 then y + 36 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 36 then y - 37 when x = 1296 then y + 37 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 37 then y - 38 when x = 1369 then y + 38 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 38 then y - 39 when x = 1444 then y + 39 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 39 then y - 40 when x = 1521 then y + 40 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 40 then y - 41 when x = 1600 then y + 41 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 41 then y - 42 when x = 1681 then y + 42 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 42 then y - 43 when x = 1764 then y + 43 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 43 then y - 44 when x = 1849 then y + 44 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 44 then y - 45 when x = 1936 then y + 45 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 45 then y - 46 when x = 2025 then y + 46 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 46 then y - 47 when x = 2116 then y + 47 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 47 then y - 48 when x = 2209 then y + 48 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 48 then y - 49 when x = 2304 then y + 49 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 49 then y - 50 when x = 2401 then y + 50 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 50 then y - 51 when x = 2500 then y + 51 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 51 then y - 52 when x = 2601 then y + 52 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 52 then y - 53 when x = 2704 then y + 53 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 53 then y - 54 when x = 2809 then y + 54 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 54 then y - 55 when x = 2916 then y + 55 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 55 then y - 56 when x = 3025 then y + 56 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 56 then y - 57 when x = 3136 then y + 57 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 57 then y - 58 when x = 3249 then y + 58 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 58 then y - 59 when x = 3364 then y + 59 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 59 then y - 60 when x = 3481 then y + 60 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 60 then y - 61 when x = 3600 then y + 61 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 61 then y - 62 when x = 3721 then y + 62 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 62 then y - 63 when x = 3844 then y + 63 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 63 then y - 64 when x = 3969 then y + 64 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 64 then y - 65 when x = 4096 then y + 65 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 83 then y - 84 when x = 6889 then y + 84 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 84 then y - 85 when x = 7056 then y + 85 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 85 then y - 86 when x = 7225 then y + 86 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 86 then y - 87 when x = 7396 then y + 87 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 87 then y - 88 when x = 7569 then y + 88 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 88 then y - 89 when x = 7744 then y + 89 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 89 then y - 90 when x = 7921 then y + 90 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 90 then y - 91 when x = 8100 then y + 91 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 91 then y - 92 when x = 8281 then y + 92 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 92 then y - 93 when x = 8464 then y + 93 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 93 then y - 94 when x = 8649 then y + 94 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 94 then y - 95 when x = 8836 then y + 95 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 95 then y - 96 when x = 9025 then y + 96 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 96 then y - 97 when x = 9216 then y + 97 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 97 then y - 98 when x = 9409 then y + 98 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 98 then y - 99 when x = 9604 then y + 99 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 99 then y - 100 when x = 9801 then y + 100 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 100 then y - 101 when x = 10000 then y + 101 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 101 then y - 102 when x = 10201 then y + 102 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 102 then y - 103 when x = 10404 then y + 103 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 103 then y - 104 when x = 10609 then y + 104 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 104 then y - 105 when x = 10816 then y + 105 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 105 then y - 106 when x = 11025 then y + 106 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 106 then y - 107 when x = 11236 then y + 107 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 107 then y - 108 when x = 11449 then y + 108 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 108 then y - 109 when x = 11664 then y + 109 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 109 then y - 110 when x = 11881 then y + 110 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 110 then y - 111 when x = 12100 then y + 111 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 111 then y - 112 when x = 12321 then y + 112 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 112 then y - 113 when x = 12544 then y + 113 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 113 then y - 114 when x = 12769 then y + 114 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 114 then y - 115 when x = 12996 then y + 115 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 115 then y - 116 when x = 13225 then y + 116 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 116 then y - 117 when x = 13456 then y + 117 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 117 then y - 118 when x = 13689 then y + 118 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 118 then y - 119 when x = 13924 then y + 119 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 119 then y - 120 when x = 14161 then y + 120 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 120 then y - 121 when x = 14400 then y + 121 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 121 then y - 122 when x = 14641 then y + 122 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 122 then y - 123 when x = 14884 then y + 123 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 123 then y - 124 when x = 15129 then y + 124 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 124 then y - 125 when x = 15376 then y + 125 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 125 then y - 126 when x = 15625 then y + 126 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 126 then y - 127 when x = 15876 then y + 127 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 127 then y - 128 when x = 16129 then y + 128 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 128 then y - 129 when x = 16384 then y + 129 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 129 then y - 130 when x = 16641 then y + 130 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 130 then y - 131 when x = 16900 then y + 131 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 131 then y - 132 when x = 17161 then y + 132 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 132 then y - 133 when x = 17424 then y + 133 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 133 then y - 134 when x = 17689 then y + 134 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 134 then y - 135 when x = 17956 then y + 135 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 135 then y - 136 when x = 18225 then y + 136 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 136 then y - 137 when x = 18496 then y + 137 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 137 then y - 138 when x = 18769 then y + 138 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 138 then y - 139 when x = 19044 then y + 139 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 139 then y - 140 when x = 19321 then y + 140 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 140 then y - 141 when x = 19600 then y + 141 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 141 then y - 142 when x = 19881 then y + 142 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 142 then y - 143 when x = 20164 then y + 143 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 143 then y - 144 when x = 20449 then y + 144 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 144 then y - 145 when x = 20736 then y + 145 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 145 then y - 146 when x = 21025 then y + 146 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 146 then y - 147 when x = 21316 then y + 147 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 147 then y - 148 when x = 21609 then y + 148 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 148 then y - 149 when x = 21904 then y + 149 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 149 then y - 150 when x = 22201 then y + 150 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 150 then y - 151 when x = 22500 then y + 151 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 151 then y - 152 when x = 22801 then y + 152 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 152 then y - 153 when x = 23104 then y + 153 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 153 then y - 154 when x = 23409 then y + 154 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 154 then y - 155 when x = 23716 then y + 155 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 155 then y - 156 when x = 24025 then y + 156 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 156 then y - 157 when x = 24336 then y + 157 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 157 then y - 158 when x = 24649 then y + 158 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 158 then y - 159 when x = 24964 then y + 159 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 159 then y - 160 when x = 25281 then y + 160 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 160 then y - 161 when x = 25600 then y + 161 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 161 then y - 162 when x = 25921 then y + 162 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 162 then y - 163 when x = 26244 then y + 163 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 163 then y - 164 when x = 26569 then y + 164 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 164 then y - 165 when x = 26896 then y + 165 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 165 then y - 166 when x = 27225 then y + 166 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 166 then y - 167 when x = 27556 then y + 167 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 167 then y - 168 when x = 27889 then y + 168 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 168 then y - 169 when x = 28224 then y + 169 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 169 then y - 170 when x = 28561 then y + 170 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 170 then y - 171 when x = 28900 then y + 171 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 171 then y - 172 when x = 29241 then y + 172 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 172 then y - 173 when x = 29584 then y + 173 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 173 then y - 174 when x = 29929 then y + 174 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 174 then y - 175 when x = 30276 then y + 175 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 175 then y - 176 when x = 30625 then y + 176 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 176 then y - 177 when x = 30976 then y + 177 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 177 then y - 178 when x = 31329 then y + 178 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 178 then y - 179 when x = 31684 then y + 179 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 179 then y - 180 when x = 32041 then y + 180 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 180 then y - 181 when x = 32400 then y + 181 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 181 then y - 182 when x = 32761 then y + 182 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 182 then y - 183 when x = 33124 then y + 183 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 183 then y - 184 when x = 33489 then y + 184 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 184 then y - 185 when x = 33856 then y + 185 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 185 then y - 186 when x = 34225 then y + 186 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 186 then y - 187 when x = 34596 then y + 187 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 187 then y - 188 when x = 34969 then y + 188 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 188 then y - 189 when x = 35344 then y + 189 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 189 then y - 190 when x = 35721 then y + 190 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 190 then y - 191 when x = 36100 then y + 191 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 191 then y - 192 when x = 36481 then y + 192 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 192 then y - 193 when x = 36864 then y + 193 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 193 then y - 194 when x = 37249 then y + 194 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 194 then y - 195 when x = 37636 then y + 195 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 195 then y - 196 when x = 38025 then y + 196 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 196 then y - 197 when x = 38416 then y + 197 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 197 then y - 198 when x = 38809 then y + 198 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 198 then y - 199 when x = 39204 then y + 199 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 199 then y - 200 when x = 39601 then y + 200 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 200 then y - 201 when x = 40000 then y + 201 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 201 then y - 202 when x = 40401 then y + 202 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 202 then y - 203 when x = 40804 then y + 203 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 203 then y - 204 when x = 41209 then y + 204 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 204 then y - 205 when x = 41616 then y + 205 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 205 then y - 206 when x = 42025 then y + 206 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 206 then y - 207 when x = 42436 then y + 207 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 207 then y - 208 when x = 42849 then y + 208 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 208 then y - 209 when x = 43264 then y + 209 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 209 then y - 210 when x = 43681 then y + 210 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 210 then y - 211 when x = 44100 then y + 211 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 211 then y - 212 when x = 44521 then y + 212 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 212 then y - 213 when x = 44944 then y + 213 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 213 then y - 214 when x = 45369 then y + 214 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 214 then y - 215 when x = 45796 then y + 215 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 215 then y - 216 when x = 46225 then y + 216 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 216 then y - 217 when x = 46656 then y + 217 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 217 then y - 218 when x = 47089 then y + 218 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 218 then y - 219 when x = 47524 then y + 219 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 219 then y - 220 when x = 47961 then y + 220 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 220 then y - 221 when x = 48400 then y + 221 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 221 then y - 222 when x = 48841 then y + 222 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 222 then y - 223 when x = 49284 then y + 223 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 223 then y - 224 when x = 49729 then y + 224 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 224 then y - 225 when x = 50176 then y + 225 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 225 then y - 226 when x = 50625 then y + 226 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 255 then y - 256 when x = 65025 then y + 256 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 256 then y - 257 when x = 65536 then y + 257 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 257 then y - 258 when x = 66049 then y + 258 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 258 then y - 259 when x = 66564 then y + 259 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 259 then y - 260 when x = 67081 then y + 260 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 260 then y - 261 when x = 67600 then y + 261 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 261 then y - 262 when x = 68121 then y + 262 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 262 then y - 263 when x = 68644 then y + 263 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 263 then y - 264 when x = 69169 then y + 264 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 264 then y - 265 when x = 69696 then y + 265 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 265 then y - 266 when x = 70225 then y + 266 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 266 then y - 267 when x = 70756 then y + 267 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 267 then y - 268 when x = 71289 then y + 268 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 268 then y - 269 when x = 71824 then y + 269 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 269 then y - 270 when x = 72361 then y + 270 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 270 then y - 271 when x = 72900 then y + 271 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 271 then y - 272 when x = 73441 then y + 272 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 272 then y - 273 when x = 73984 then y + 273 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 273 then y - 274 when x = 74529 then y + 274 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 274 then y - 275 when x = 75076 then y + 275 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 275 then y - 276 when x = 75625 then y + 276 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 276 then y - 277 when x = 76176 then y + 277 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 277 then y - 278 when x = 76729 then y + 278 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 278 then y - 279 when x = 77284 then y + 279 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 279 then y - 280 when x = 77841 then y + 280 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 280 then y - 281 when x = 78400 then y + 281 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 281 then y - 282 when x = 78961 then y + 282 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 282 then y - 283 when x = 79524 then y + 283 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 283 then y - 284 when x = 80089 then y + 284 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 284 then y - 285 when x = 80656 then y + 285 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 285 then y - 286 when x = 81225 then y + 286 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 286 then y - 287 when x = 81796 then y + 287 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 287 then y - 288 when x = 82369 then y + 288 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 288 then y - 289 when x = 82944 then y + 289 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 289 then y - 290 when x = 83521 then y + 290 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 290 then y - 291 when x = 84100 then y + 291 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 291 then y - 292 when x = 84681 then y + 292 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 292 then y - 293 when x = 85264 then y + 293 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 293 then y - 294 when x = 85849 then y + 294 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 294 then y - 295 when x = 86436 then y + 295 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 295 then y - 296 when x = 87025 then y + 296 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 296 then y - 297 when x = 87616 then y + 297 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 297 then y - 298 when x = 88209 then y + 298 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 298 then y - 299 when x = 88804 then y + 299 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 299 then y - 300 when x = 89401 then y + 300 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 300 then y - 301 when x = 90000 then y + 301 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 301 then y - 302 when x = 90601 then y + 302 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 302 then y - 303 when x = 91204 then y + 303 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 303 then y - 304 when x = 91809 then y + 304 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 304 then y - 305 when x = 92416 then y + 305 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 305 then y - 306 when x = 93025 then y + 306 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 306 then y - 307 when x = 93636 then y + 307 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 307 then y - 308 when x = 94249 then y + 308 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 308 then y - 309 when x = 94864 then y + 309 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 309 then y - 310 when x = 95481 then y + 310 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 310 then y - 311 when x = 96100 then y + 311 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 311 then y - 312 when x = 96721 then y + 312 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 312 then y - 313 when x = 97344 then y + 313 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 313 then y - 314 when x = 97969 then y + 314 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 314 then y - 315 when x = 98596 then y + 315 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 315 then y - 316 when x = 99225 then y + 316 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 316 then y - 317 when x = 99856 then y + 317 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 317 then y - 318 when x = 100489 then y + 318 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 318 then y - 319 when x = 101124 then y + 319 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 319 then y - 320 when x = 101761 then y + 320 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 320 then y - 321 when x = 102400 then y + 321 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 321 then y - 322 when x = 103041 then y + 322 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 322 then y - 323 when x = 103684 then y + 323 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 323 then y - 324 when x = 104329 then y + 324 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 324 then y - 325 when x = 104976 then y + 325 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 325 then y - 326 when x = 105625 then y + 326 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 326 then y - 327 when x = 106276 then y + 327 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 327 then y - 328 when x = 106929 then y + 328 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 328 then y - 329 when x = 107584 then y + 329 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 329 then y - 330 when x = 108241 then y + 330 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 330 then y - 331 when x = 108900 then y + 331 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 331 then y - 332 when x = 109561 then y + 332 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 332 then y - 333 when x = 110224 then y + 333 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 333 then y - 334 when x = 110889 then y + 334 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 334 then y - 335 when x = 111556 then y + 335 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 335 then y - 336 when x = 112225 then y + 336 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 336 then y - 337 when x = 112896 then y + 337 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 337 then y - 338 when x = 113569 then y + 338 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 338 then y - 339 when x = 114244 then y + 339 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 339 then y - 340 when x = 114921 then y + 340 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 340 then y - 341 when x = 115600 then y + 341 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 341 then y - 342 when x = 116281 then y + 342 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 342 then y - 343 when x = 116964 then y + 343 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 343 then y - 344 when x = 117649 then y + 344 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 344 then y - 345 when x = 118336 then y + 345 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 345 then y - 346 when x = 119025 then y + 346 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 346 then y - 347 when x = 119716 then y + 347 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 347 then y - 348 when x = 120409 then y + 348 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 348 then y - 349 when x = 121104 then y + 349 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 349 then y - 350 when x = 121801 then y + 350 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 350 then y - 351 when x = 122500 then y + 351 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 351 then y - 352 when x = 123201 then y + 352 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 352 then y - 353 when x = 123904 then y + 353 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 353 then y - 354 when x = 124609 then y + 354 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 354 then y - 355 when x = 125316 then y + 355 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 355 then y - 356 when x = 126025 then y + 356 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 356 then y - 357 when x = 126736 then y + 357 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 357 then y - 358 when x = 127449 then y + 358 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 358 then y - 359 when x = 128164 then y + 359 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 359 then y - 360 when x = 128881 then y + 360 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 360 then y - 361 when x = 129600 then y + 361 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 361 then y - 362 when x = 130321 then y + 362 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 362 then y - 363 when x = 131044 then y + 363 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 363 then y - 364 when x = 131769 then y + 364 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 364 then y - 365 when x = 132496 then y + 365 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 365 then y - 366 when x = 133225 then y + 366 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 366 then y - 367 when x = 133956 then y + 367 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 367 then y - 368 when x = 134689 then y + 368 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 368 then y - 369 when x = 135424 then y + 369 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 369 then y - 370 when x = 136161 then y + 370 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 370 then y - 371 when x = 136900 then y + 371 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 371 then y - 372 when x = 137641 then y + 372 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 372 then y - 373 when x = 138384 then y + 373 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 373 then y - 374 when x = 139129 then y + 374 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 374 then y - 375 when x = 139876 then y + 375 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 375 then y - 376 when x = 140625 then y + 376 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 376 then y - 377 when x = 141376 then y + 377 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 377 then y - 378 when x = 142129 then y + 378 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 378 then y - 379 when x = 142884 then y + 379 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 379 then y - 380 when x = 143641 then y + 380 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 396 then y - 397 when x = 156816 then y + 397 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 397 then y - 398 when x = 157609 then y + 398 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 398 then y - 399 when x = 158404 then y + 399 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 399 then y - 400 when x = 159201 then y + 400 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 400 then y - 401 when x = 160000 then y + 401 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 401 then y - 402 when x = 160801 then y + 402 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 402 then y - 403 when x = 161604 then y + 403 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 403 then y - 404 when x = 162409 then y + 404 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 404 then y - 405 when x = 163216 then y + 405 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 405 then y - 406 when x = 164025 then y + 406 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 406 then y - 407 when x = 164836 then y + 407 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 407 then y - 408 when x = 165649 then y + 408 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 408 then y - 409 when x = 166464 then y + 409 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 409 then y - 410 when x = 167281 then y + 410 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 410 then y - 411 when x = 168100 then y + 411 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 411 then y - 412 when x = 168921 then y + 412 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 412 then y - 413 when x = 169744 then y + 413 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 413 then y - 414 when x = 170569 then y + 414 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 414 then y - 415 when x = 171396 then y + 415 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 415 then y - 416 when x = 172225 then y + 416 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 416 then y - 417 when x = 173056 then y + 417 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 417 then y - 418 when x = 173889 then y + 418 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 418 then y - 419 when x = 174724 then y + 419 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 419 then y - 420 when x = 175561 then y + 420 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 420 then y - 421 when x = 176400 then y + 421 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 421 then y - 422 when x = 177241 then y + 422 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 422 then y - 423 when x = 178084 then y + 423 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 423 then y - 424 when x = 178929 then y + 424 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 424 then y - 425 when x = 179776 then y + 425 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 425 then y - 426 when x = 180625 then y + 426 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 426 then y - 427 when x = 181476 then y + 427 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 427 then y - 428 when x = 182329 then y + 428 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 428 then y - 429 when x = 183184 then y + 429 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 429 then y - 430 when x = 184041 then y + 430 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 430 then y - 431 when x = 184900 then y + 431 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 431 then y - 432 when x = 185761 then y + 432 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 432 then y - 433 when x = 186624 then y + 433 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 443 then y - 444 when x = 196249 then y + 444 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 444 then y - 445 when x = 197136 then y + 445 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 445 then y - 446 when x = 198025 then y + 446 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 446 then y - 447 when x = 198916 then y + 447 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 447 then y - 448 when x = 199809 then y + 448 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 448 then y - 449 when x = 200704 then y + 449 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 449 then y - 450 when x = 201601 then y + 450 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 450 then y - 451 when x = 202500 then y + 451 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 451 then y - 452 when x = 203401 then y + 452 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 452 then y - 453 when x = 204304 then y + 453 else 0 end)+(case  when x = 453 then y - 454 when x = 205209 then y + 454 else 0 end)) * ((case  when x + y = 1 then y - 2 when x = 1 then y + 2 else 0 end)+(case  when x + y = 2 then y - 3 when x = 4 then y + 3 else 0 end)) as tst from spktest cll")
```

So, my questions are:
Is there an actual hard limit in the complexity of expressions that can be run in Spark SQL? If yes, can that limit be set to a higher level than what it is by default? If not, what is the recommended course of action to circumvent the problem?

(The expressions I am dealing with are complex enough that they cannot be easily broken into a series of intermediate steps)

Thanks

Comment: Note that I have tried persisting the data before running the large query with this: `sqlContext.cacheTable('spktest')`
and `sqlContext.sql('select count(*) from spktest').collect()`. Also I have tried setting `spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage` to false according to this: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/114561/spark-thrift-server-configs-to-work-around-few-err.html but I am still getting the error.